# How to call migrations in Laravel from one microservice to another?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, migration, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I'm building my DB test in memory and I need to make migrations run before running tests
The problem is I have this tests in one microservice and migrations in another
So I need something like:

```
class MyTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    public function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp(); 
        $path = str_replace('api', 'admin', base_path()) . '/database/migrations/';
        Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => $path]);
    }
    
    public functions myFunction()
    {

    }

}
```

I tried to run:

```
$path = str_replace('api', 'admin', base_path()) . '/database/migrations/';
        echo PHP_EOL . $path . PHP_EOL;
        Artisan::call('migrate', ['--path' => $path]);
```

Where 'api' is one project and 'admin' is another one

But it did not work out. Also some other combinations of the migration path did not work out
I have two services on my PC running in vagrant and working fine
I just can't find a way how to build a command that will call migrations from one service to another
So...how do I do this? Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: You do not use migrations from another project into your project. You can create a package and share common code like models and migrations, but we need more info here

Comment: Well it's actually one project but just sepparated into few microservices one of which contains all migrations in order to not mess things up

Comment: You could create a post request using curl or guzzle from your microservice a to run a migration to microservice b( make sure you set you it properly where the db migrated is for testdb not actual running db) once you are done in your test (or has thrown an error in try catch), then you can run another request to drop the db.(again set it properly)

Comment: @Mr.Kenneth but would it work? I mean I have test DB in memory so if I call endpoint in another microservice where I call something like Artisan::call('migrate') would it actually make migrations in memory DB?

Comment: Does not hurt to try.

Answer (score 0):

In order you've faced the same issue when your project is divided into few Laravel microservices and migrations leave in one of them but your test is in another one here is few choices up to you:

1. Symlink. Yes. Just create a symlink to migrations from one sub project to another one. We didn't really used it in practice but it might be a way
2. The solution we did: just create a sepparate DB not in memory(is it even usefull?), then use once the command:

   php artisan migrate --database=db_for_test_name

And in DB tests then add DatabaseTransactions that locks the state of you test DB before tests and bring it back after test worked no matter failed it or not.
It will help you save migration history in migration table and rerun the command above when you have new migrations